# fconfigure in TCL -mode error

Tags: serial-port, tcl

I see this error has been around for a while but no one could give a solution to it. I am facing it at the moment. Here is my code:

```
set cfgVxWxConsoleAttr "/dev/ttyS3 115200,N,8,1"  
# set cfgVxWxConsoleAttr "com4 115200,N,8,1"  

 # ------------------------------------------------------  
 # Start console  
 #  
 proc console_start {} {

    global consoleAttr  
    global consoleFileDescriptor

    set com [ lindex $consoleAttr 0 ]
    set baud [ lindex $consoleAttr 1 ]
    set fd [ open $com { RDWR } ]

    fconfigure $fd -mode $baud \
               -buffering line -translation cr \
               -blocking 0 \
               -buffersize [ expr 1024 * 1024 ]

    set consoleFileDescriptor $fd

    return $fd
 }
```

But when running it I get the following error:

> bad option "-mode": should be one of -blocking, -buffering,
>   -buffersize, -encoding, -eofchar, or -translation while executing "fconfigure $fd -mode $baud  -buffering line -translation cr 
>   -blocking 0  -buffersize [ expr 1024 * 1024 ]"

Why is this? and what is the fix? With knowing that I already tried to open fileDescriptor(fd) for that com port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Tcl is not detecting that `/dev/ttyS3` is the device for a serial port (since the `-mode` option is present exactly when the detection succeeds). There are a few possible reasons for this, one of which is that it might not actually be a serial port; I think that's really unlikely though.

What's much more likely is that the build of the installation of Tcl that you're using was built in a way that disabled the serial support, which was due to an unfortunate interaction between the way Tcl's build scripts detected what serial API to use and the environment in which the build happened at the Linux distribution maker: Tcl's `configure` script smartly detects that the system isn't using a terminal at all at that point and promptly removes *all* serial support! This is fixed in 8.6 (which doesn't support some of the really old Unix serial control APIs any more — the termio API has been superseded by the termios API for years, and who uses sgtty any more at all? — and so can behave in a much more robust fashion) but in 8.5 and 8.4, there's a definite problem.

### Possible Workarounds

1. Upgrade to 8.6
2. Build your own Tcl 8.5 or Tcl 8.4 from source.

Comment: I am in Cygwin and tcl that comes with it is 8.5. In Cygwin we cannot do apt-get! In Linux box I also see there is no 8.6, is it out? How can I get it for my Cygwin?

Comment: @Mehdi Sources are available from http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/8.6.html (which also has links to binary builds for various platforms — including Windows — from ActiveState).

Comment: Thank you, it works now with tcl8.6 that you suggested.

Comment: I've a 8.6.6 tclkitsh.exe and it displays the error when executing a script but doesn't when interactive. Now what?

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, the `-mode` option was moved to the [`open`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/open.htm) command.

Comment: That's entirely wrong; that's just where it is documented.